# installed xfce / xRDP on AWS - XKB extension not present on

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce, qt

I just moved to install 4.1 XFCE on my AWS Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) and I can't get the keyboard mappings to work ... yep, tried lots of stuff.

I'm trying to use Spyder (Anaconda Python Debugger) and get below error messages (mouse works fine in Spyder, key entry does nothing ...):
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
Qt: Could not determine keyboard configuration data from X server, will use hard-coded keymap configuration.

### Qt: Failed to compile a keymap!

$ setxkbmap
XKB extension not present on :10.0

So I'm trying to figure out how to set my keyboard correctly in XFCE, seems I'm missing something fundamental with the mappings.

the xrdp mappings are present, /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini but can't seen to persist.

Any help appreciated,
Craig

EDIT: 
$ spyder (python Qt based IDE)

```
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
Qt: Could not determine keyboard configuration data from X server, will use hard-coded keymap configuration.
Qt: Failed to compile a keymap!
Current XKB configuration data search paths are: 
/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib
Use QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT environmental variable to provide an additional search path, add ':' as separator to provide several search paths and/or make sure that XKB configuration data directory contains recent enough contents, to update please see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/ .
$ setxkbmap -query
XKB extension not present on :10.0
$ echo $XKB_DEFAULT_RULES
base
```

Comment: Do you mind showing which command you run and which failed?

Comment: The `setxkbmap` command is provided by the `x11-xkb-utils` package. (Are you really on an Ubuntu machine?)

Comment: yes, this is on an AWS instance. I followed the AWS instructions: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/              $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Comment: Ok.. I don't know anything about AWS, but what about installing the `x11-xkb-utils` package?

Comment: Gunnar, thanks but no change. i'm going to try rebuilding the AWS instance, thinking something failed during the build.

Comment: After doing more digging, I added  `$ export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb  
$ spyder  
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I run into the same issue when I try to import matplotlib...